# Can you println something and do a function based on the last println?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I have a tableview and when someone taps on a row, I want to println(rowtext) and then segue to another viewcontroller. In the new view controller I was hoping to use the rowtext from the println to use as a title and query rowtext. Is this possible.

Woops, fixed the post "rowtext" wasnt showing.

Comment: If you have something to print, why wouldn't you just use that value instead of what was printed to the console?

Comment: so like, prepare for segue and set a variable? in the new view controller there are buttons that lead to other view controllers and I was hoping to just refer to the last println instead of having to prepare for segue for all of the controllers, not sure if that made sense (im new).

Comment: Sorry, but you'll have to `prepareForSegue` like that if you want to pass data along. You could use local notifications or KVO too but based on what I think you're saying you're trying to accomplish `prepareForSegue` will be your best bet.

Comment: so it isnt possible to just refer to your last println?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. And this would be bad Program design too.

Comment: okay ill just prepare segue. felt like i needed to ask because ive been wondering this for a while. thanks

Comment: if i prepare segue and set a var name = row.text[indexrow.path], in the next view controller when i prepare segue again what do i set the var name equal to because i cant put var name = row.text[indexrow.path] again.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get data from a print statement. Try making a global variable to pass the data...

Follow these steps...

1: Create a Separate file called Manager.swift and place this code in it...

//manager.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Manager {

static var rowNumber = Int()


}
```

2: Clean your project by pressing Shift+Command+K.

3: In the first view controller set the rowNumber to the data you want to pass...

```
Manager.rowNumber = self.dataToPass
```

4: In the second view controller retrieve the data and set the content to the rowNumber...

```
self.dataToReceive = Manager.rowNumber
```

5: Your Finished!!

Comment: if i prepare segue and set a var name = row.text[indexrow.path], in the next view controller when i prepare segue again what do i set the var name equal to because i cant put var name = row.text[indexrow.path] again.

Comment: Change the rowNumber to an array.

Answer (score 0):

From the segue you can access the destination view controller with:

`ViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];`

Set a property on the destination controller (say rowText) and do:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"]) 
    {
        ViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        destViewController.rowText = <rowtext that you want to pass>;

    }
}
```

If you are embedded in a nav controller, use:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[segue destinationViewController];
ViewController *destViewController = (YourViewController* )[navController topViewController];
destViewController.rowText = <rowtext that you want to pass>;
```